# Receiving alerts/commands from Azure IoT Hub to device using NodeJS

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-node-sdk

Can any one suggest me how to receive Message/payload on RPI as device sent to Azure IoT Hub.

I am using **SimulatedDevice.js** and sending data with interval of every 5 seconds to Azure IoT Hub that data is going to store in Azure table storage from windows machine using NodeJS. Everything working Ok.

Now I want to receive complete message/payload from IoT Hub to RPI as device.

I have used **sendcloudtodevicemessage.js** as given example on Azure.
I am able to recieve message only only once as below

```
[{"originalMessageId":"My Message ID","description":"Success","deviceGenerationId":"636341763976720081","deviceId":"testDevice","enqueuedTimeUtc":"2017-07-18T09:50:27.991313Z","statusCode":"Success"}]
```

But I want to recieve message on device each time.

Can any one help me for this?

Comment: Exactly, this sample `sendcloudtodevicemessage.js` send **one** Cloud-To-Device message. If you run this sample one time you will receive only one message as expected.

Comment: But How to receive repeatedly/continue payload/message on device?
I want to receive message in device whenever Azure Data store to Cloud.
Can you suggest me ?

Comment: What's your os running on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I am running simulatedDevice.js on windows which sends data to Azure IoT Hub when user enter any input from console or random message/payload with interval of 5 seconds.
when I enter any input from cmd to simulatedDevice.js I am able to store that data in Azure Storage using functions.
On other hand i have SendCloundToDevice.js in RPI So I want to receive the same message on RPI when user enter any input from windows.

Comment: Currently I am able to get only one message and how to get message payload because currently I am only getting message info not message data i mean payload which I had sent from SimulatedDevice.js.

Comment: You can get message payload(body) using [`msg.data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d#receive-messages-in-the-simulated-device-app).

Comment: but how to get continue data on RPI when user send a new data to Azure IoT hub each time from cmd? 
Can you please suggest me if possible?